# Menu Block Appears When Page NOT in Any Menus

Tags: 7, routes, blocks

Let me describe the site/block issue:

1. The site has multiple menus.
2. We use a menu block to generate a left-column menu that follows active trail. Attached is a screencap of the settings we're using for our block. Menu block settings page has a few of the menus we use on the site checked off (why we're using "the menu selected by the page" for menu).

[image: Screencap of the current settings for the menu block.]

The issue right now is that the menu block will appear on all nodes, even ones not defined in ANY menu at all, as opposed to hide when not in menu.

We can hide it using the block visibility settings, but preferably it would be nice to fix this issue so that it just auto-hides when it does not detect a menu associated with the node.

Is there a fix or something I'm setting wrong to cause this issue to happen? Or am I doomed to just use block visibility to control it?